# Linux Toolchain for TI CCXXXX SoC Chips

Tags: linux, wireless, linux-toolchain, system-on-chip

I am trying to do a project using TI CC2510 wireless SoC chips, but I want to use Linux to load my C code onto the devices. I don't want to buy Windows just for my development purposes. Does anyone know if this can be done? If so, once I compile to the 8051 hardware, how do I actually load the file onto the device? Can I somehow use this in linux? http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/cc-debugger.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cctool/

Comment: What is it? Lone link is bad.

Comment: How do you install it? I tried running automake in the parent directory, but nothing seems to happen...